# Material UI Menu using routes

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am toying with material-ui. I implemented LeftNav using routes, but I could not find a way to get IconMenu, or Menu working with links or routes. Anyone can point me to a good source / tutorial? The documentation falls short, and both components seem not to support 'menuItems' as property as LeftNav does.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

another long overdue update:

`containerElement` prop is not supported anymore, use `component` prop instead.

Check out the document [here](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/#props).

---

***2016 December Edit:*** the `linkButton` prop is **deprecated**, you will get a warning:

```
Warning: Unknown props `linkButton` on <a> tag.
```

So simply remove the prop:

```
<MenuItem
  containerElement={<Link to="/profile" />}
  primaryText="Profile"
  leftIcon={
    <FontIcon className="material-icons">people</FontIcon>
  }
/>
```

[Here's an Example Repo](https://github.com/DaxChen/material-ui-Link-within-MenuItem), and [the Live Demo Here](https://daxchen.github.io/material-ui-Link-within-MenuItem).

---

***Original answer:***

Just wanted to point out that if you're using react-router, you might want to use `<Link to="/some/page" />` rather than the `<a>` tag.

To do this, you need to use the `containerElement` prop

```
<MenuItem
  linkButton
  containerElement={<Link to="/profile" />}
  primaryText="Profile"
  leftIcon={
    <FontIcon className="material-icons">people</FontIcon>
  }
/>
```

(the `={true}` can be omitted if you're only passing `true`,
in other words, `<MenuItem linkButton />` is same as `<MenuItem linkButton={true} />`)

The `containerElement` and `linkButton` props is actually documented [in the buttons section](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button), but you can use it in `MenuItem` as well.

Comment: link now broken and cannot see any button link docs anywhere on the site. This might be what I am after so thanks for posting. I am not sure what you mean by te true stuff ?

Comment: Updated, thanks for reminding! (Updated the true stuff too)

Comment: I also see the onTouchTap is a way to get an event from interacting with a menu item.

Comment: Yeah, but using `onTouchTap`/`onClick` to trigger page change instead of `<a>`/`<Link />` you lose some native functions such as the link preview in browser, and the ability for users to open link in a new tab.

Comment: This does not work for me, see https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/204#issuecomment-296499846

Comment: Not working in 2020 , containerElement no longer supported

Comment: In 2021 you should use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019285/1757878

Answer (score 48):

Starting with Material-UI 1.0, the new syntax is:

```
<MenuItem
  component={Link}
  // the 'to' prop (and any other props not recognized by MenuItem itself)
  // will be passed down to the Link component
  to="/profile"
>
  Profile
</MenuItem>
```

(Note: this example doesn't include an icon. There is a new `ListItemIcon` component for that.)

Comment: Perfect... As I needed.

Comment: This works with `ListItem` from Material UI as well.

Comment: Works in v5, which the top answer didn't for me

Comment: Not a fan of passing down props implicitly, plus it wont work with typescript. Way better to just do this: `component={()=><Link to='/profile'/>}`

Comment: Maybe I'm doing smth wrong, but ``` const menuItems: MenuItemProps[] = [{id: 'someId', children: 'Go', component={Link}}] ``` and se the error - `Type '{ id: string; onClick: () => void; children: string; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MenuItemProps<"li", {}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' does not exist in type 'MenuItemProps<"li", {}>'.
`. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 13):

You can set the `linkButtton` prop on `MenuItem` to generate a link, then also add an `href`.

```
<MenuItem linkButton={true} href="link/to/some/page" primaryText="Sample Link" />
```

Comment: If this was true, it doesn't seem to be true anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 11):

None of the existing answers (of September 2018) worked for me with react 16.4.2 and react-router 4.2.2, so this was my solution:

```
<Link to='/notifications' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
   <MenuItem>Notifications</MenuItem>
</Link>
```

As you can see, the MenuItem component is surrounded by the Link component, and I added a style `textDecoration: 'none'` not to have the item underlined.

Comment: I had to add `outline: "none"` too.

Comment: Thank you. It's amazing that such basic info is missing from https://material-ui.com/components/menus/

Comment: This works, but puts the `li` inside the `a`, which semantically makes no sense

Comment: Exactly and this results that it cannot be navigated with arrow.

Answer (score 9):

As of Sep 2020, only thing that works and is super simple is

```
<MenuItem component="a" href="/your-path">Click Me</MenuItem>
```

Bonus:  To add icon with a badge:

```
<MenuItem component="a" href="/your-path">
        <IconButton color="inherit" href="/your-path">
              <Badge badgeContent="12" color="secondary">
                <StarsSharpIcon color="action"/>
              </Badge>
        </IconButton>
Click Me
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: It works but you should be aware that using `a` causes page reloads.

Answer (score 7):

The prop `linkButton` of `EnhancedButton` is deprecated. LinkButton is no longer required when the `href` property is provided.
It will be removed with v0.16.0.

```html
<MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose} href="/link/data">Link Item</MenuItem>
```

Works fine

Comment: this is the best answer as of 11/29/2016 you can also use things like `target="_blank"` to get the link to open in a new browser window

Comment: This is an option but that will reload the whole page, while `Link`'s element doesn't. It's possible instead to simply wrap the `MenuItem`: ```<Link to='/'><MenuItem>Home</MenuItem></Link>```

Answer (score 6):

### **2023 Answer:**

```
import {Menu, MenuItem, Link} from '@mui/material'

<Menu>
  <MenuItem component={Link} href='/'>Home</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem component={Link} href='/settings/user'>My Settings</MenuItem>
<Menu />
```

As of writing in 2023 a lot of the answers above have been deprecated, tested using MUI v5.11.6.

Passing in a `Link` as the `component` prop of a `MenuItem`, uses a `Link` as the root element of that `MenuItem`. Documentation on additional things you can do with a `Link` element can be found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-link/)

Comment: Cheers! This one works best despite some other solutions also working. It doesn't add any additional styling.

Answer (score 5):

Using M-UI 4.x you can set a `component` prop on `MenuItem` and to something like

```
<MenuItem component='a' href='link/to/some/page'>Sample Link</MenuItem>
```

Comment: It works but you should be aware that using `a` causes page reloads.

Comment: What's the implication of `a` causing page reloads?

Comment: @jkschin react is typically used in a single page application manner (SPA), wherein one of the benefits is avoiding full page reloads.

Answer (score 5):

From [v5.2.2](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.2.2) you can use:

```
import { MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<MenuItem component={Link} to="/profile">
  Profile
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 3):

After doing a little searching myself I went with a slightly different solution:

```
<MenuItem onClick={() => {handleClose("/#about")}}>About me</MenuItem>
```

With a supporting JS function:

```
function handleClose(nav) {
    window.location.href = nav;
}
```

Hopefully proves of use as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


<MenuItem component={Link} to='/login'>
       Login
</MenuItem>
```

That worked for me, September 2021, by using React Router and the Link prop of the MenuItem.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with the v5

for external links

```
<MenuItem
    component={"a"}
    href={"https://example.com"}
>Go here</MenuItem>
```

or internal links

```
import { MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<MenuItem
    component={Link}
    to={"/users/2323"}
>Go here</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

We should use `<Link>` tag out side of `<MenuItem>` tag

**Error:**

```
     <MenuItem>
        <ListItemText>
            <Link to='/ticket-blotter' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                TICKET BLOTTER 
            </Link>
        </ListItemText>
     </MenuItem>
```

**Solution:**

```
        <Link to='/ticket-blotter' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
            <MenuItem>
                <ListItemText>
                    TICKET BLOTTER
                </ListItemText>
            </MenuItem>
        </Link>
```

Comment: I believe it should have been `<Link href='/ticket-blotter' sx={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>`

Answer (score 1):

onTouchTap doesn't work for me I have to use onClick see the example below

```
  <MenuItem 
    onClick={this.logout}
    containerElement={<Link to="/" />}
    primaryText="Sign out"
    rightIcon={
      <b style={style.rightIcon}>
        <img
          className="menu-img"
          src="img/app/logout.png"
          alt="logout"
        />
      </b>
    }
  />
```

hope this will help others as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use **react-route-dom** and MenuItem **onClick** attribute first import react-router-dom:

`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'`

then declare a function to handle your onClick within your component:
`const navigate = () => history.push('route/to/navigate')`
 and then user your MenuItem 
`<MenuItem onClick={navigate}>Navigate</MenuItem>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, which looks exactly like what in the material-ui official website. The component you can use include `AppBar`, `Drawer` and `ListItem`. The `SelectableList` can be implemented as `let SelectableList = MakeSelectable(List)`.

```
<div>
  <AppBar 
    onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleLeftIconButtonTouchTap}
    title={title}
    showMenuIconButton={true}
    zDepth={0}
  />
    <Drawer 
      open={this.state.open} 
      docked={true} 
      onRequestChange={(open, reason) => {
        this.setState({open:false})
      }}
    >
      <AppBar title={title} />
      <SelectableList
        value={location.pathname}
        onChange={this.handleRequestChangeList}
       >
        <Subheader>Selectable Contacts</Subheader>
        <ListItem
          value={"link1"}
          primaryText="Link1"
        />
        <ListItem
          value={"link2"}
          primaryText="Link2"
        />
      </SelectableList>
    </Drawer>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the `containerElement` work on Safari in iOS with `react-router`. I'm using `0.17.2` of Material UI and `react-router@v3` and here's a work around that worked for me:

```
  <MenuItem
    onTouchTap={() => {
      this._yourMethod()
      browserHistory.push('/howItWorks')
    }}
    primaryText="Menu Link"
  />
```

Comment: It doesn't help to just down vote an answer without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const YourComponentName = () =>{
  
    const history = useHistory();
    const handleRoutes = (path) =>{
       history.push(path)
    }
    
  return(
    <>
      ...
      <MenuItem onClick={()=>handleRoutes('/dashboard')}>Dashboard</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={()=>handleRoutes('/profile')}>Profile</MenuItem>
      ...
    </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use onClick and window.open OR any other way to redirect with a button click

```
 <MenuItem value={'On Map'} onClick={()=> window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self')}>
                    On Map
                </MenuItem>
```