# React material-ui MenuItem containerElement not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have following code:

```
<MenuItem primaryText="home" containerElement={<Link to="/" />} />
```

But it doesn't work as explained in other topics/threads where MenuItem discussed like here [Material UI Menu using routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106513/material-ui-menu-using-routes).
Once i add containerElement prop to MenuItem i'm getting this exception:

```
Uncaught Error: 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
Check the render method of `EnhancedButton`.
```

Comment: How do you import your `Link`?

Comment: This is the import
`import Link from 'react-router';`

Comment: Not sure it's main problem, but should be `import { Link } from 'react-router';`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that no longer works (will need to find the change log.)

To fix this I did `npm install react-router-dom --save` and used the following snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer'

    <Drawer
         docked={false}
         open={this.state.open}
         onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}>
         <MenuItem onTouchTap={() => {this.handleClose()}} >
              <NavLink to="/">Home </NavLink>
         </MenuItem>
         <MenuItem onTouchTap={() => {this.handleClose() }} >
              <NavLink to="/about"> About Us </NavLink>
         </MenuItem>
    </Drawer>
```