# how navigate using the MenuItem? material-ui V1

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Why it is not clear how a [MenuItem](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/menus/) makes navigation to other route?

for example, when clicks on a menu item, I want to route to '/account'

I can manage to achieve that using onclick function, but I am sure that there is an easier way. Pleas tell me about it I want to implement it on my project.

By the way, when used the containerElement `containerElement={<Link to="/dashboard" />}` I get the following error:

```
index.js:2177 Warning: React does not recognize the `containerElement` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `containerelement` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in li (created by ButtonBase)
    in ButtonBase (created by withStyles(ButtonBase))
    in withStyles(ButtonBase) (created by ListItem)
    in ListItem (created by withStyles(ListItem))
    in withStyles(ListItem) (created by MenuItem)
    in MenuItem (created by withStyles(MenuItem))
    in withStyles(MenuItem) (at MenuAppBar.js:116)
    in ul (created by List)
    in List (created by withStyles(List))
    in withStyles(List) (created by MenuList)
    in MenuList (created by Menu)
    in div (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by withStyles(Paper))
    in withStyles(Paper) (created by Popover)
    in Transition (created by CSSTransition)
    in CSSTransition (created by Grow)
    in Grow (created by withTheme(Grow))
    in withTheme(Grow) (created by Popover)
    in div (created by Modal)
    in Portal (created by Modal)
    in Modal (created by withStyles(Modal))
    in withStyles(Modal) (created by Popover)
    in Popover (created by withStyles(Popover))
    in withStyles(Popover) (created by Menu)
    in Menu (created by withStyles(Menu))
    in withStyles(Menu) (at MenuAppBar.js:101)
    in div (at MenuAppBar.js:92)
    in div (created by Toolbar)
    in Toolbar (created by withStyles(Toolbar))
    in withStyles(Toolbar) (at MenuAppBar.js:77)
    in header (created by Paper)
    in Paper (created by withStyles(Paper))
    in withStyles(Paper) (created by AppBar)
    in AppBar (created by withStyles(AppBar))
    in withStyles(AppBar) (at MenuAppBar.js:76)
    in div (at MenuAppBar.js:62)
    in MenuAppBar (created by Connect(MenuAppBar))
    in Connect(MenuAppBar) (created by withStyles(Connect(MenuAppBar)))
    in withStyles(Connect(MenuAppBar)) (at Test.js:9)
    in div (at Test.js:7)
    in Test (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:37)
    in Switch (at App.js:34)
    in div (at App.js:32)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:31)
    in div (at App.js:30)
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App) (at index.js:34)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by MuiThemeProviderWrapper)
    in MuiThemeProviderWrapper (at index.js:33)
    in Provider (at index.js:32)
```

When I fixed that error by `containerElement` -> `containerelement` the error has disappeared, that is a good news, but the bad news is that the menu doesn't go for the mentioned rote in the Link!

MenuAppBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import AccountCircle from 'material-ui-icons/AccountCircle';
import Switch from 'material-ui/Switch';
import { FormControlLabel, FormGroup } from 'material-ui/Form';
import Menu, { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';

import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const styles = {
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};

class MenuAppBar extends Component {

  state = {
    auth: true,
    anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleChange = (event, checked) => {
    this.setState({ auth: checked });
  };

  handleMenu = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    // console.log(this.props.auth)
    // if(!this.props.auth)
      // return <div> Loading... </div>;

    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { auth, anchorEl } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>



        {/* the log switch */}
       {/* <FormGroup>        
                 <FormControlLabel
                   control={
                     <Switch checked={auth} onChange={this.handleChange} aria-label="LoginSwitch" />
                   }
                   label={auth ? 'Logout' : 'Login'}
                 />
               </FormGroup>*/}

        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>

            {/*
            <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="contrast" aria-label="Menu">
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton> */}

            <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
              المواعيد
            </Typography>



            {/*If logged in */}
            {this.props.auth && (
              <div>
                <IconButton
                  aria-owns="menu-appbar-logged"
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  onClick={this.handleMenu}
                  color="contrast"
                >
                  <AccountCircle />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  id="menu-appbar-logged"
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                  }}
                  open={open}
                  onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  {/*Changing font for this text is on the them and there search for subheading*/}
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}  containerelement={<Link to="/dashboard" />}>الملف الشخصي</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose} href="/api/logout">تسجيل الخروج</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            )}
            {/*end*/}




            {/*If logged out */}
            {!this.props.auth && (
              <div>
               <Button color="contrast" href="/auth/google/">تسجيل الدخول</Button>
              </div>
            )}
            {/*end*/}


          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

MenuAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps({auth}){
  return {auth}
}

export default withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuAppBar));
```

**Updae**

I found another problem caused by the proposed solution below by Mr. @Gavin Thomas  that refers to the post on SO. The problem is that using  is just putting  the mentioned 'to' attribute value in the URL linked to the existing route without going to that path, i.e

```
<MenuItem onTouchTap={() => {this.handleClose()}}><NavLink to="/api/logout">Sign Out</NavLink></MenuItem>
```

ends up having the link on the browser as http://localhost:**3000**/logout, without going there on the logout route at the nodejs backend server! that is a problem.

Note that I use  proxy to directs from **3000** to **5000** as follows

```
 "proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
```

Generally speaking, I guess that is because the difference between  and !

So please help me solve this 2nd problem!

Comment: post your entire page of code, we need to see everything...

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: try import menuItem like this.... ===> import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';  and import Menu seperately, then change back to containerElement

Comment: Did like that, got Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/MenuItem'.   Please take care of the post title, I said material-ui V1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271690/react-material-ui-menuitem-containerelement-not-working

Try this? I'm still searching for you, your code should work I'm unsure why it's not ATM.

I also found this, last updated 8 days ago so pretty recent https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/204

Comment: Thanks for your determination! <NavLink to="/"> is the solution. So please update your first reply with that SO post, I will vote it up and make it the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4411 Not home currently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Heres what we found out...

You now need to use < NavLink > vs Link

[React material-ui MenuItem containerElement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271690/react-material-ui-menuitem-containerelement-not-working)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer'

    <Drawer
         docked={false}
         open={this.state.open}
         onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}>
         <MenuItem onTouchTap={() => {this.handleClose()}} >
              <NavLink to="/">Home </NavLink>
         </MenuItem>
         <MenuItem onTouchTap={() => {this.handleClose() }} >
              <NavLink to="/about"> About Us </NavLink>
         </MenuItem>
    </Drawer>
```

Comment: I used the containerElement but had an error. let me try it again and paste the error in the post.

Comment: Are you sure you also setup your browser router?

Comment: |  updated post, looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: updated the post because of problem caused by the solution of that post on SO. Please check that.

Answer (score 19):

You should use the `component` property.  It is okay to use the `Link` component from react-router-dom:

```
<MenuItem component={Link} to="/logout">
  Logout
</MenuItem>
```

The `containerElement` attribute was used in v0.x and no longer exists as of v1.

Please refer to the docs for [MenuItem](https://material-ui-next.com/api/menu-item/)

Comment: thank you for reply, I did your solution and I still get the 'to' attribute value being tied to existing URL! as I descriped in my update at this answer, and also opened a new post here for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875453/navlink-only-ties-its-to-attribute-value-to-existing-url-menuitem-on-materia

Comment: That has nothing to do with the original issue, which was how you can configure MenuItem so that it navigates to a route.  The simplest way to do so is in the way I've outlined in my answer.

Comment: How do you handle this with TypeScript? When you use `component={Link}`, then add `to=""`, you get `[ts] Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MenuItemProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.`

Comment: Just answered my own question, this worked: `<MenuItem  component={Link} {...{ to: route.path}}>`...