# Navlink only ties its 'to' attribute value to existing URL | MenuItem on material-ui new version (v1)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

When I want to navigate using the `<MenuItem>` as follows

```
<MenuItem onTouchTap={() => {this.handleClose()}}>
 <NavLink to="/api/logout">Sign Out</NavLink>
</MenuItem>
```

that is just putting the mentioned 'to' attribute value `/api/logout` in the URL linked to the existing route without going to that path and ending up having the link on the browser as http://localhost:3000/api/logout, without going there on the logout route at the nodejs backend server! that is a problem.

Note that I use proxy to directs from **3000** to **5000** as follows

```
 "proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
```

Generally speaking, I guess that is because the difference between `<Link>` and `<NavLink>`.

If you would like to know more about from where this problem has come out, you can take a look at my previous post [how navigate using the MenuItem? material-ui V1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873566/how-navigate-using-the-menuitem-material-ui-v1) but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with me when I updated the code as:

```
<MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose} ><a href="/api/logout">Sign Out</a></MenuItem>
```