# React-router route won't trigger

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

First, i am sorry if this problem has been asked before. I am currently new to react-router, i don't know what to ask. So, i am trying to make a sidebar component in my apps, this sidebar composed of material-ui drawer, listItems. Each listItem has a link i put as its containerElement attribute value. Selecting each list does change the url, but component that each route should display won't show.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'

var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();

const ListItem = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>List Item</h2>
  </div>
)

const CreateForm = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Create Form</h2>
  </div>
)

const SearchItem = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Search Item</h2>
  </div>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Sidebar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={ListItem}/>
            <Route path="/create" component={CreateForm}/>
            <Route path="/search" component={SearchItem}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer'
import {List, ListItem, makeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List'
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List)

function wrapState(ComposedComponent) {
  return class SelectableList extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      })
    }

    handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          value={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </ComposedComponent>
      )
    }
  }
}

SelectableList = wrapState(SelectableList)

const ListSelectable = () => (
  <SelectableList defaultValue={1}>
    <Subheader>Basic CRUD operation</Subheader>
    <ListItem
      value={1}
      primaryText="List"
      containerElement={<Link to='/'/>}
    />
    <ListItem
      value={2}
      primaryText="Create"
      containerElement={<Link to='/create'/>}
    />
    <ListItem
      value={3}
      primaryText="Search"
      containerElement={<Link to='/search'/>}
    />
  </SelectableList>
);

class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer>
        <ListSelectable />
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}

export default Sidebar
```

Note: The selectable list implementation i copied from material-ui docs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106513/material-ui-menu-using-routes/34507786#34507786

Comment: @James111 I visited the link you give, and checked his example repo. The implementation doesn't much differ than mine. Any hint why my code doesn't work ?

Comment: @James111 Moving my route to root component as used in that link you give me still not work, the link shown, url changed, but the route component doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I suggest you follow a tutorial such as this: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf Make sure your code follows the correct rules that react-router sets!

Comment: @James111 Ooh, my route does rendered, its render behind the material-ui drawer. Thank for the reply btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component is covered by the sidebar. Try to put some margin on the left.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'

var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();

const ListItem = () => (
  <div>
    <h2 style={{marginLeft:'300'}}>List Item</h2>
  </div>
)

const CreateForm = () => (
  <div>
    <h2 style={{marginLeft:'300'}}>Create Form</h2>
  </div>
)

const SearchItem = () => (
  <div>
    <h2 style={{marginLeft:'300'}}>Search Item</h2>
  </div>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Sidebar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={ListItem}/>
            <Route path="/create" component={CreateForm}/>
            <Route path="/search" component={SearchItem}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes, it is, i just saw it.
Any way to make the sidebar absolute so i don't need to add margin ? or different material-ui component maybe ?