# React router Link won't update route after if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, p5.js

I hope this question hasn't been answered yet somewhere and I haven't found it...
So I'm still new to React.js but always trying new things with it, anyways.

I've already done my research but none of the proposed solutions seem to work for me. I'll leave some examples of what I've search for:

[How to use Redirect in the new react-router-dom of Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs)

[Redirecting in React](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a)

[React-router route won't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341115/react-router-route-wont-trigger)

So I basically have this piece of code:

```
clicked(mousePosX, mousePosY) {
 let d = property.dist(mousePosX, mousePosY, this.x, this.y);
 if (d < this.w && d < this.h) {
  console.log("square"); //working until here
  return <Link to="/test/" />; //not redirecting
 }
}
```

I have it inside a ***class*** which creates a square with help from the p5 library which is also ***inside*** a const arrow function.

I've also tried to change the Link tag to a Redirect tag, no luck.

If you'd like to see the whole file (or project) here's a link:

[Whole file (github)](https://github.com/Sarquamon/englishKiddoGame/blob/development/src/components/Levels/Level1/Sketch.js)

What I want it to do is to redirect the user somewhere else after the user clicks on any on-screen square.

I'll be thankful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<Link/>` doesn't redirect to somewhere else untill you click on it, to redirect programmatically you need to use `<Redirect/>` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Link/>` doesn't redirect to somewhere else untill you click on it, to redirect programmatically you need to use `<Redirect/>` component.

Update your `clicked` function, when user clicks on the square box, set redirect variable to true in state.
and in render function check if `redirect` is true, if it's `true` then use `<Redirect/>` component to redirect somewhere else otherwise return your other UI component.

Here is how a basic state setup should look like-

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        redirect: false,
        //other state data
    }
}
```

```
clicked(mousePosX, mousePosY) {
 let d = property.dist(mousePosX, mousePosY, this.x, this.y);
 if (d < this.w && d < this.h) {
  console.log("square"); 

  this.setState({
    redirect:true, //set redirect to true
  });

 }
}
```

In your render function

```
render(){
    if(this.state.redirect){
        return <Redirect to="/test" />
    }
    else{
        //return something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

link tag should be used with any html tag as follows
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start