# Material UI v1+ how to use a MenuItem with component={Link}

Tags: material-ui

I m migrating from Material UI v0.20 to v1.2.3+ and I couldnT find a way to put a Link inside a MenuItem.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106513/material-ui-menu-using-routes?answertab=active#tab-top) a solution is proposed as sth like this:

```
      <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}
        component={<Link to="/edit" />}
        disabled={!props.canEdit}
        onClick={() => props.handleCardAction('EDIT')}
      >
```

But I couldnT quite get it right.

How can I use a Link component inside the MenuItem?

EDIT:

Wrapping the `MenuItem` inside the `Link` works, but it looks ugly: [ref](https://forums.meteor.com/t/active-link-on-sidebar-with-react-router-material-ui-drawer/26650)

```
<Link to="/edit">
        <MenuItem className={classes.menuItem}
          disabled={!props.canEdit}
          onClick={() => props.handleCardAction('EDIT')}
        >
          <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
            <EditIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.primary }} inset primary="Edit" />
        </MenuItem>
      </Link>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, the intended way is this:

```
<MenuItem
    component={Link}
    to="/edit"
    className={classes.menuItem}
    disabled={!props.canEdit}
    onClick={() => props.handleCardAction('EDIT')}
>
    Bla
</MenuItem>
```

More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234539/405015).